# Error handling in shell script

Tags: shell

I have the following the shell script. Which throws the following error if there is no file exist in the folder. So, how we do handle this so that script doesn't stop executing?

Error:

```
   mv: cannot stat `*': No such file or directory
```

Script:

```
for file in *
    do
        fl=$(basename "$file")            
        flname="${fl%%.*}"              
        gunzip "$file"
        mv "$flname" "$flname-NxDWeb2" 
        tar -zcf "$flname-NxDWeb2".tar.gz "$flname-NxDWeb2"
        rm "$flname-NxDWeb2"   
done;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the shell is `bash`, you can allow `*` to expand to the null string: `shopt -s nullglob` before your loop.

BTW, you might want to explicitly specify the uncompressed filename to produce, in case your logic doesn't completely agree with `gunzip`'s (which it probably won't, if there's more than one dot in the name, or the file ends with `.tgz` or `.taz`):

```
gunzip -c "$file" >"$flname"
```

(you will need to remove the original yourself in this case, though)

You can avoid the need to move, too:

```
flname="${fl%%.*}-NxDWeb2"
```

And you might want to use `trap` to ensure your temporaries are cleaned up in the failure case (possible make your temporaries in `$TMPDIR`, too).